# launching already launched activity from notification creating problematic activity

Tags: android, android-intent

i have 3 activities A-B-C .Lets say i am on activity B and from a listview there i launch activity C now if a notification comes which has an intent of launching activity C.
So the problem is I am getting multiple instances of activity C
When i use launchMode singleTop or instance or task the problem of multiple activity instance is solved but the newly launced activity does not work properely as it is desired to be.

Please help me out tired of using flags and stuff but not able to overcome this problem.

The scenario is Just like whatsapp , if u r talking to person one and a message of person 2 come as notification ,when u click on that notification the activity relaunches and works properely. This is exactly what i want. Please help me out how to achieve this . :(

Thanxx in advance

Answer (score 0):

What Flags did you try and what exactly is not working, means, how does the Activity behave?

What you describe with WhatsApp could be achieved with two steps:

- Use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP for the Activity.
- Overwrite the `Actvity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method in the Activity. This method is called instead of creating a new `Activity` and gives you the new `Intent`. I assume that the Intent contains all necessary information in the extras.

The user experience should be as follows:

- User chooses from the list, which opens the new Activity
- He/she can press home or back button from here. This brings the home screen or the list back.
- If, for any reason, somebody else calls `startActivity` for your Activity while it is running, the `onNewIntent` is called. There you can add code to refresh the content, maybe have an Alert that tells the user that the content has changed, and shows all that to the user.
- If the user presses back or home now, he/she will get to the list or home screen

If that is, what you're looking for, then the flag and the method is what you need

Comment: I have allready tried this. No success. The previous instance of the activity is still running.

Comment: With the `singleTop` flag set there can be only one instance running. This one will continue to run, when the Activity is launched again and mo second instance will be created. His is what you should get, right? Then the way to react on the second launch is by overriding `onNewIntent`. Try to log that call to see that itbbasically does was it should do. Then you need to implement all changes as other functions like `onCreate` are not called at this time.

Comment: Tried this already. Wjhen on newIntent is called the values changes perfectly but the problem is,handler in the same activity before running onnewIntent is still running and after clicking the notification all other values change but handler of previous one is still running therefore their are two same handlers running now and again I click the notification 3 same handlers run and so on

Comment: Now I understand! What kind of handler is it? Can you cancel it somehow?

Comment: I am using handler like this.                mHandler.post(new Runnable( void run(){setlistadapter();}));

Comment: Then you can do one of two things (maybe both): (1) in `onNewIntent()` call [`Handler.removeCallback(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)). You must have the the Runnable defined as `private static`in the Activity. And/Or (2) do calls to `setListAdapter` and the like directly, without post and Handler. You can call directly whenever you're in the UI Thread, e.g. whenever you're in a callback of an Activity like `onCreate`, `onPause` etc.

Comment: ill try the first one out and post it here if its a success.

Comment: @jboi- i have tried this , but when i exit my activity , the handler is still running . i.e. when i come back from activity C to activity B i am geting the logs of previous activity still the handler portion is still running

Comment: The handler code portion is like :  mhandler.post(new Runnable( void run (setListAdapter())))

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the `Runnable` to be able to cancel it later. Like this `Runnable myR = new Runnable(){void run(){setListAdapter()}}; mhandler.post(myR);` Later, when canceling, you do `mhandler.removeCallback(myR);` BTW: If you want to show, that this is helpful, can you please upvote the answer instead of the comment? Upvoting comments doesnt even get me informed - for any reason of Stackoverflow.

Comment: The scene is when i click the notification the onNewIntent gets caled , here i am cancelling the handler.works fine for 2-3 times but after that it ,isnt behaving right dont know why